# want to run a video file from python?

Tags: cron, python

Want to run the following code through python every 5 min ?

--> bash -c "display=:0 cvlc vish.mp4"

If i run this command directly its working good but how to use it in a python file ?

any suggestions please.

thank you

Comment: You should ask this on StackOverflow which is dedicated to programming questions

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps APScheduler will help : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/APScheduler. You can use cron-style (periodic) scheduling or at-style (delayed), for example.